# Call global object function from another object function within an if scope

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope, conditional-statements

The answer might be simple but bear with me.  I have the following code:

```
//Global Scope
var mask = {
    active: function() {
        $('#c-mask').addClass('is-active');
    },
    inactive: function() {
        $('#c-mask').removeClass('is-active');
    }
};

//Global Scope
var barObj = {
    show: function() {  //Within another scope
        //Trying to call the function in multiple places to see where it works. 
        mask.active();  //This works!! 
        if (true) {                                  //Within if scope
            $('#sidebar3').addClass('is-active');
            mask.active();  //This does NOT work.  Why? :-(
            this.mask.active();  //Does not work.
            window.mask.active();  //Does not work.
            return function() { mask.active(); } // Does not work
            console.log(mask.active();) // Does not work
        }
    }
};
```

Both objects are defined within the global scope.  But calling mask.active() within the if scope does not work. (Does if even have a scope?) I think I'm probably missing something obvious since I'm new to this. I've tried using closures and even return functions.  Nada. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you've already called `mask.active()` BEFORE the `if (true)` statement, why would you expect a second `mask.active()` call to do anything, since you've already turned on that class? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "does not work"? What happens when you run the code? Do you get any error message?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gmg5rec0/ check this..you will understand whether your functions are getting called

Comment: There is no reason why it wont work. "mask" will refer to the same variable defined in global scope even if you pass the "show" function around, "mask" variable will be accessible through closure. "this.mask" is an error.

Comment: @torazaburo I only left the other calls there to show where the function call worked and where it didn't work.  I only intend to call the function once.  I am more wondering why it works inside one scope and why it doesn't within the if statement.  I've run it multiple times through the debugger.  Chrome inspector and so forth.  Thanks again.  I'll edit the question to reflect this desire.

Comment: by the way, in javascript, only functions form a scope other than global scope. for, while, if etc blocks don't form a scope.

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir I see what you've written.  I've run it through the console.  All the returns work.  No console logs though.  Thanks.  I had already attempted something similar before posting the question.

Comment: Aaargh.  Sorry all.  My conditional was evaluating improperly.  I had used the wrong syntax so I guess I did not debug sufficiently, although, I'd spent a few hours with this.  Thanks for the help everyone.  Didn't mean to   ask a stupid question.